# Caliburn Micro Action inside ItemContainerStyle - No target found for method

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, treeview, caliburn.micro

I'm working on a WPF project using Caliburn Micro as a framework for MVVM, and during the last week I've been lucky enough to find every solution to any problem on StackOverflow, but now I'm facing a bigger issue that I can't solve by myself.

I have a View containing a TreeView; each item of the treeview should invoke a method when:

- it is double clicked [working]
- an entry of its context menu is clicked [not working]

This is the TreeView:

```
<TreeView x:Name="projectTreeView"
              Visibility="{Binding ExplorerVisibility, Converter={StaticResource visibilityConverter}}">
        <TreeViewItem Header="{Binding ProjectName}" IsExpanded="True">
            <TreeViewItem Header="Category 1"/>
            <TreeViewItem Header="Category 2" ItemsSource="{Binding Images}">
                <TreeViewItem.ItemContainerStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="TreeViewItem">
                        <Setter Property="ContextMenu">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <ContextMenu>
                                    <MenuItem Header="Remove"
                                              cal:Action.TargetWithoutContext="{Binding Path=DataContext, ElementName=projectTreeView}"
                                              cal:Message.Attach="[Event Click] = [Action RemoveResource()]"/>
                                </ContextMenu>
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                    </Style>
                </TreeViewItem.ItemContainerStyle>
                <TreeViewItem.ItemTemplate>
                    <HierarchicalDataTemplate>
                        <HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemContainerStyle>
                            <Style TargetType="TreeViewItem">
                                <Setter Property="IsExpanded" Value="True" />
                                <Style.Triggers>
                                    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Collapsed">
                                        <EventTrigger.Actions>
                                            <BeginStoryboard>
                                                <Storyboard>
                                                    <BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames 
                                    Duration="0" 
                                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="(TreeViewItem.IsExpanded)">
                                                        <DiscreteBooleanKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="True" />
                                                    </BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                </Storyboard>
                                            </BeginStoryboard>
                                        </EventTrigger.Actions>
                                    </EventTrigger>
                                </Style.Triggers>
                            </Style>
                        </HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemContainerStyle>
                        <ContentControl cal:Action.TargetWithoutContext="{Binding Path=DataContext, ElementName=projectTreeView}"
                                        cal:Message.Attach="[Event MouseDoubleClick] = [Action OpenResource(projectTreeView.SelectedItem)]">
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding ResourceName}" Margin="5,0,0,0"/>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </ContentControl>

                        <HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding}"/>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>

                    </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
                </TreeViewItem.ItemTemplate>
            </TreeViewItem>
        </TreeViewItem>
    </TreeView>
```

The attached ViewModel contains both methods:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    ...

    public void OpenResource(object obj) { ... }

    public void RemoveResource() { ... }

}
```

For some reason **OpenResource** works perfectly, while when I click on the context menu item (after right click) the application crashes with the exception:

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.Exception' occurred in WindowsBase.dll

Additional information: No target found for method RemoveResource.
```

I found something related to the same problem here on the forum and on the support forum, but I was not able to fix the problem with those tips.

Do you have any idea about what's going on in my TreeView?

Thank you very much for the help!

Comment: Is RemoveResource() should have a object obj parameter?

Comment: http://caliburnmicro.codeplex.com/discussions/287228 Check if this works for you (the last post of EisenbergEffect).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `ContextMenu` resides in its own visual tree and can't bind to the `TreeView` using an `ElementName`.

You could try to bind the `Tag` property of the `TreeViewItem` to the parent `TreeView` and then bind to it using the `PlacementTarget` property of the `ContextMenu`:

```
<Style TargetType="TreeViewItem">
    <Setter Property="Tag" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=TreeView}}" />
    <Setter Property="ContextMenu">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ContextMenu>
                <MenuItem Header="Remove"
                                  cal:Action.TargetWithoutContext="{Binding Path=PlacementTarget.Tag.DataContext, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=ContextMenu}}"
                                  cal:Message.Attach="[Event Click] = [Action RemoveResource()]"/>
            </ContextMenu>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Comment: Thank you very much man, you are great! It works, I just had to edit the TargetWithoutContext a little bit:

cal:Action.TargetWithoutContext="{Binding Path=PlacementTarget.Tag.DataContext, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=ContextMenu}}"

Could you please update the answer for future reference?

Now I have the final question: how do I pass the object bound to the TreeViewItem to RemoveResource? Thanks again!!!

Comment: I've updated the answer. Please ask a new question if you have a new issue. It's a bit messy to answer in the comments.

Comment: I found by myself, it was as easy as using [Action RemoveResource($datacontext)].

Thank you very much again, I really had no idea how to solve! :)