# Handling TreeViews context menu with WPF and MVVM

Tags: wpf, mvvm, caliburn.micro

I have a application that shows a `TreeView`. The `TreeView` has a context menu. I use Caliburn.Micro as MVVM framework.

The line `cal:Message.Attach="[Event Click]=[Action Remove()]"` is required so that something happens if the ContextMenu-Item is clicked. This line makes that Caliburn.Micro searches in the ViewModel of the TreeItem for a method with the name Remove.

But I want that the click on the `ContextMenu` Item will call the method Remove of the ViewModel of the screen. How to do that?

```
<TreeView.ItemTemplate>
    <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Children}">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}">
            <TextBlock.ContextMenu>
                <ContextMenu>
                    <MenuItem cal:Message.Attach="[Event Click]=[Action Remove()]" Name="Remove" Header="Remove item" />
                </ContextMenu>
            </TextBlock.ContextMenu>
        </TextBlock>
    </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
</TreeView.ItemTemplate>
```

Comment: Or is it better to handle deletion logic inside the ViewModel of the TreeItem itself (including removing the DTO from database?)

Comment: Somebody had the similar problem [link(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24825722/bubbling-events-from-bound-viewmodel-goes-to-parent). And according to author himself:[link[(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3650800/bind-a-command-to-a-button-inside-a-listview-with-caliburn-micro). So just call it by convention or like this      `<i:Interaction.Triggers>
         <i:EventTrigger EventName="Click">
             <cal:ActionMessage MethodName="{Binding Name}" />
          </i:EventTrigger>
     </i:Interaction.Triggers>`

Comment: i posted the answer if this solved your problem

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<TreeView.ItemTemplate>
    <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Children}">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}">
            <TextBlock.ContextMenu>
                <ContextMenu>
                    <MenuItem Tag="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=TreeView}}"
                              cal:Action.TargetWithoutContext="{Binding Path=PlacementTarget.Tag.DataContext, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=ContextMenu}}"
                              cal:Message.Attach="[Event Click]=[Action RemoveResource()]" Name="Remove" Header="Remove item" />
                </ContextMenu>
            </TextBlock.ContextMenu>
        </TextBlock>
    </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
</TreeView.ItemTemplate>
```

Please refer to my answer here for more information:

[Caliburn Micro Action inside ItemContainerStyle - No target found for method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42348574/caliburn-micro-action-inside-itemcontainerstyle-no-target-found-for-method/42349127#42349127)

Answer (score 0):

Somebody had the similar problem [“Bubbling” events from bound viewmodel goes to parent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24825722/bubbling-events-from-bound-viewmodel-goes-to-parent).

And according to author himself [Bind a Command to a Button inside a ListView with Caliburn.Micro](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3650800/bind-a-command-to-a-button-inside-a-listview-with-caliburn-micro).

So just call it by convention or like this:

```
<i:Interaction.Triggers>
    <i:EventTrigger EventName="Click">
        <cal:ActionMessage MethodName="{Binding Name}" />
    </i:EventTrigger>
</i:Interaction.Triggers>
```